# I Setup Rate My Post Plugin On Site But Now Got Issues In Google Webmasters

Tags: plugins

I have recently installed Rate My Post plugin on my WordPress coupons site and added a few ratings to different coupons stores such as this one https://grabhosts.net/deals/globehost-promo-code/ and as you can see in the post there that the ratings are shown & working fine.

Now after a few hours (I think, 10 Hours Later), I got an email from Google Webmaster saying the following:

> Products issues detected on https://grabhosts.net/
>
> To the owner of https://grabhosts.net/:
>
> Search Console has identified that your site is affected by 5 Products
>   issues:
>
> Top Warnings
>
> Warnings are suggestions for improvement. Some warnings can affect
>   your appearance on Search; some might be reclassified as errors in the
>   future. The following warnings were found on your site:
>
> No global identifier provided (e.g., gtin, mpn, isbn)
>
> Missing field "sku"
>
> Missing field "offers"
>
> Missing field "brand"
>
> Missing field "review"
>
> We recommend that you fix these issues when possible to enable the
>   best experience and coverage in Google Search.

You can also check the screenshot below.

[image: WordPress Site Issue]

I'd like to know if I need to remove the plugin or do anything else. Your help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As Google stated, these warnings are suggestions for improvement. If you care about having your items listed as products in Google shopping, you should look into fixing the issue. If that doesn't apply, you don't necessarily have to address it. Typically for the best SEO, you do want to resolve this type of warning - if you don't offer actual products, figure out what's generating product markup and remove it, or if you do, figure out how to add the missing information.